# Wordpress 5.4. REST API get post by slug not working

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

I have a fresh install of the latest version of wordpress. I need to pick up a certain post by slug from the REST API, but the response is always all posts instead of the one.

[My route](https://wp.illuminosdigital.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=working-from-home-with-illuminos-solutions)

I cannot find the reson I'm getting all posts as the response anywhere on the internet. What am I missing??

Answer (score 0):

By default, WordPress will work with slug filtering but in your scenario, it shows all posts created. I found an alternative way & try below link which shows only mentioned slug data.

[REST API](https://wp.illuminosdigital.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[order]=desc&filter[posts_per_page]=1&slug=working-from-home-with-illuminos-solutions)